# I need some advice on how to organize some drafts and what to with a new formula I found

Tags: bernoulli-numbers, formal-power-series

Found a new formula to get the sum of k to the power of any positive integer , k from 1 to n .I know bernoulli already found another formula in which he created his bernoulli numbers. This new fomula also requires new set of numbers  that I created, they are relatively easier to generate.  This still in drafts... can anyone tell me how to write it properly and what to do next?

Comment: I think it would help if you gave us some of your results.  I mean, the coefficients are determined by the definition...so, surely your numbers must be the same as the old ones, no?

Comment: @lulu well no they are different and the formula is different from bernoulli's ... but I found a links between the two sets of numbers... I would gladly share the results but I just want to know first if this has some impact... or to what extent  it could be used

Comment: How can anyone judge the impact of something they haven't seen?

Comment: Well ,it is just messy and lots of drafts but  if I told you about a  formula similar to bernoulli's but with easier sets to generate what would you say ?

Comment: I'm trying to give you a window here.  People will soon vote to close your question because there's really nothing for anybody to say about it.  If you want to generate a useable response, you have to present some results.  If you don't want to, fine!  But then I suggest you delete your question.

Comment: Well that's the first problem I don't know how to present my results can you help me

Comment: No.  I'm not going to read something that's "messy" and "lots of drafts".  The Bernoulli numbers are of enormous interest, for many, many reasons.  If you have a new family of numbers with similar properties, state their definition and list the first few.  Maybe they are of interest, maybe not. Impossible to say without information.

Comment: I sure Will.  I asked you how can I go from drafts to clean notes

Comment: This is not a good forum in which to discuss broad issues of writing and such, it just isn't.  If you attend, or are near, a university you can try to find someone there who can review your results.  Even then, however, I suggest that you first prepare a brief, clear statement of what you think you have demonstrated.  That should take a few lines to state, maybe a full paragraph.  Otherwise you might find it hard to get their attention.

Comment: @lulu look here is the thing plain and simple im a medical student ... I just like to tinker with numbers and I found this formula I have no experience on what to do next , im gonna look somewhere else. But thanks for your attention

Comment: There is also a version with the so called "Eulerian numbers" known - perhaps you've rediscovered this "sum-of-like-powers" solution? Here is an example (however in german) how I tried myself structuring some discovery in a mathematical essay. It was my first one, (being nearly an amateur) and later my essays became more concise and for instance filled with references (well: a bit, at least...) see: http://go.helms-net.de/math/potenzsummen/potenzsummen_1.htm